# How to properly group data for analysis

Tags: group-differences, multivariable

I am wondering what the most common way to handle data is wherein a participant belongs to multiple groups. For example, if you're wanting to run linear regression and look at how specific diet-type (IV/predictor) effects a specific health outcome (DV/response variable) and you have a few participants that are on a combination of 2 diet types (lets say "Mediterranean" AND "Vegetarian") and you actually want to know how Mediterranean outcomes are different than Vegetarian, how do you handle those participants? I know you could make another group that's a combination diet type, but not if you have too small of an N for that. Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

One possibility might be to divide your `Diet` variable into two separate variables: `Diet` and `Vegetarian`:

```
ID    Diet           Vegetarian
1     Mediterranean  TRUE
2     Mediterranean  FALSE
3     Atkins         FALSE
4     Low Carb       TRUE
...
```

This would give you a large amount of flexibility in how you analyze your data later on, since groups can always be combined.  It is also very conducive to multivariate or subgroup analysis.

A second possibility would be to make Diet a many-to-one (that is, "many" diets to "one" subject) variable:

```
ID    Diet
1     Mediterranean
1     Vegetarian
2     Mediterranean
3     Atkins
4     Low Carb
4     Vegetarian
...
```

In this particular case, I would prefer the former approach, as `Diet` and `Vegetarianism` seem to me to be separate variables.  However, this really depends on your particular dataset and how you intend to analyze your data later.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I guess I should have made an example that uses my specific problem. I am wanting to look at a certain health outcome by medication use. I have run into the problem that some participants are on 2 drugs of a given class - so comparing class A1 to class A2's effects on the health outcome is tricky. Additionally, some people are on a drug in class A and a drug in class B, and I want to be able to compare A to B. The first splitting example you gave would be ideal, but I can't think of a way to do it...

Comment: Brandon, welcome to this site! Please register your account, and follow the instructions in our Help center to [merge your two accounts](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion, hope it helps!

Suppose our null hypothesis is that drug A and drug B have the same effect on a population. We would expect 2 things

1) We would expect the mean effect size of drug A and mean effect size of drug B to be the same i.e.  $\bar{A} - \bar{B}$ will have mean 0 (you can make some judgement call regarding the variance of the effects (they are the same/they are not the same). Then use standard CLT-like arguments to either accept or reject this null hypothesis .

2) Suppose from 1 you conclude that $A$ has a significant effect and $B$ doesn't. If we believe the combination is just the sum of the 2 effects I would expect the mean effect size of $A$ and $X$ to have the same effect where $X$ is a person taking both drugs. In this case, my null hypothesis will be $\bar{A} -\bar{X}$ has zero mean. You can again use 
CLT based arguments to infer a significance.  (Modify the null hypothesis in part 2 on the basis of the findings in part 1).